# Extract "defined" type from property in TypeScript at runtime

Tags: node.js, typescript, types

### What I want to do

I'm currently looping over an object's keys and transferring the values to another object.

```
interface From {
    [key: string]: string;
}

let from: From = {
    prop1: "foo",
    prop2: "23",
};

interface To {
    [key: string]: string | number | boolean | undefined;
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;
    prop3: boolean;
}

let to: To = {} as To;

const initEnv = async () => {
    const keys: string[] = Object.keys(from);

    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        let key: string = keys[i];

        let keyType = typeof (key as keyof To); // This only returns "string". Which kind of makes sense to me

        let keyType = typeof keyof key; // SyntaxError: ',' expected

        let keyType: typeof to[key]; // Error: 'key' refers to a value, but is being used as a type

        to[key] = from[key];
    }
};
```

I would want to be able to, say switch the value, so I don't want to just extract the type of the key. I want to assign it to a variable for use in the code, thus at runtime, as a string for instance.
So I think things like this wouldn't work.

```
let keyType2: typeof env[key]; // Error: 'key' refers to a value, but is being used as a type
```

Maybe, but the question is then; what do I assign to this variable?

The reason for all this, is that I want to convert the `from variables` to the correct type before, assigning them to the `to` object.

So yeah, basically, my question is how I would **extract** the type (as a string, at runtime, dynamically) from the `key`. Or is it even possible in the first place? And if it isn't why not? I like understanding things.

Thanks for putting up with my bad english, as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are no `interface`s at runtime; TypeScript's type system is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) from the emitted JavaScript. Your `from` and `to` values will be evaluated like this at runtime:

```
let from = {
    prop1: "foo",
    prop2: "23",
};
let to = {};
```

There's no `From` or `To`, and no way to use `To` to figure out how to coerce `from`'s properties into the right types.   The type system has no runtime effects.

---

The usefulness of TypeScript's type system comes from *describing what will happen at runtime* and not from affecting things at runtime.  Imagine how you would have to write your code in pure JavaScript, and then give types to *that* code.  Here's one way I might do it.  Instead of a `To` interface, let's make a `To` object whose properties are functions that coerce inputs to other types:

```
const To = {
  prop1: String,
  prop2: Number,
  prop3: Boolean
}
```

This is enough information to proceed at runtime.

---

Now, if you were going to build `to` *manually*, the compiler would be able to understand that the resulting value has a `prop1` property of type `string` and a `prop2` property of type `number`:

```
const toManual = { prop1: To.prop1(from.prop1), prop2: To.prop2(from.prop2) };
/* const toManual: { prop1: string; prop2: number; } */
```

But you don't want to do it manually; you'd like to write a *loop* that walks through the keys of `from` and uses `To` to produce properties of `to`.  This is harder for the compiler to understand, but with judicious use of [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) and type annotations you can write an `objMap` function that works programmatically:

```
function objMap<T, F extends { [K in keyof T]: (arg: T[K]) => any }>(
  obj: T, fMap: F) {
  const ret = {} as { [K in keyof T]: ReturnType<F[K]> };
  const fM: { [K in keyof T]: (arg: T[K]) => ReturnType<F[K]> } = fMap;
  (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>).forEach(<K extends keyof T>(k: K) => {
    ret[k] = fM[k](obj[k]);
  })
  return ret;
}
```

The `objMap` function takes an object `obj` and a mapping object `fMap` which has at least all the same keys as `obj` and whose properties are functions that map `obj`'s properties.  The return type of `objMap` is an object whose properties are all the returned values of the `fMap` function for each property in `obj`.  The actual work is being done by `ret[k] = fM[k](obj[k]);`.  It's the programmatic equivalent of `ret.prop1 = To.prop1(from.prop1);` and `ret.prop2 = To.prop2(from.prop2)`.

Let's see if it works:

```
const to = objMap(from, To);
/* const to: { prop1: string; prop2: number; } */

console.log(JSON.stringify(to));
// {"prop1":"foo","prop2":23}
```

That looks correct; the type of `to` is inferred by the compiler to be `{prop1: string, prop2: number}`, and the actual value of `to` is computed at runtime to be `{prop1: "foo", prop2: 23}`.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/LAKANgpgLgBAZgJwPYFsYF4YG9QxgB2XwEYAuGAIjiSQoBpcCiAmci5gZntAF8BuUKADGSAHYBnWABUkGbI0JIS5AMpQEAS1EBzBiDyL8rGADkArigBGEBHoNEO5AEI1IAQ1G9BIERNhQkAFkPMzcwOSwmJTIYGQA6Q2IACkRUBKJiAEo6KKNyeMNmFOQUdKVmTJh+UAB6ACoYX0kYAODRULBySMTySU0dPlzjdqsbQZ4YOprvUDgzUSEoDTEYJEsAK2D8AB4pHIAxGAgADygIUQATcWwYAG0AaRgtGABrCABPJDhYgF1yJLcCG0+QeP0q6AAfDAPO8qhCkow1ut8jk4FtyPtKjh9I0xM0ENAIhM3NdIg8nqJXh8vr9yAAlaBmBCiKTvfAQbb7UFQ6o4pqwNFdO6PZ5vT7fKR-GAAoEg+5gjBQhlQJkstkcrnynlyNFufACHFJADyGwgiziYvESSRlRJMAAgggEG53tsxTSpBDMnFqAgAKJuIQACyS20eJzOl2u7ol8Je5Hu4Kh2LweAJUFuLx+OsCmZ+1o2ecyBrwPEyjHTqpg6YNPFw3n5LVkmCRW2KqByMmLtQajYCQp6MD6Wm0g0K5BG1gQ40m0xAwjxSEgcTASG0SQAUiojSY4sOdBo4O8kgFMt2QDUatgKIkKKQqDR6DeWHfOHX5yAgA)

Comment: OMG! How long did it take you to come up with that? Well it took me 20 minutes to understand. Thank you so, so much! This is perfect and will definitely do.